# Import contacts in Outlook in one group

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have more than 500 contacts which I put in a CSV file and imported into Outlook 2013.

Now in Outlook, I am able to see them but my problem is that I need to manually create a group and add them one by one to it.

Is it possible to directly import these contacts to Outlook in a one group?

Comment: I don't think Outlook Contact Groups can hold that many contacts. I'm trying to find the info to back that up.

Comment: consider it for 100 contacts for example,can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy and paste into a Contact Group.

1. Highlight and copy the names and emails in Excel.
2. Create your new Contact Group.
3. Open the Add New Members dialog.
4. Instead of selecting members to add, place the cursor in the text
   field and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
6. Name your Contact Group and save.

Now you should have a Contact Group with those contacts in it.

[Source](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/772)

Comment: This is great, it solved my problem.